# Multidimensional Array (with some values not sub-arrays) to string?

Tags: php

I am trying to turn a multidimensional array into a patterned string with this `array_map` function:

```
function array_to_string($array) {
    return implode("&",array_map(function($a){return implode("~",$a);},$array));
}
$arr = array("hello",array("blue","red"),array("one","three","twenty"),"random");
array_to_string($arr);
```

Between each array element "&" and between each sub-array element (if it is an array) "~"

Should Output: `hello&blue~red&one~three~twenty&random`

However this outputs: `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed` (2)
I tried changing the function within the `array_map` to detect whether the multi-array's value `is_array` but from my outputs, I don't think that is possible? So essentially, I guess the real question is how can I place a test on the `array_map` function to see whether or not it `is_array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a can be an array or a string, you should check it in your callback function:

```
function array_to_string($array) {
    return implode("&",
               array_map(function($a) {
                   return is_array($a) ? implode("~",$a) : $a;
               }, $array)
           );
}
```